# How to find elements on android hybrid app using appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, appium

I am trying to test Hybrid App using Appium.
I am not able to inspect ids using `Appium` inspector or `uiautomatorviewer`. It shows only one class for app. 
I tried to inspect id elements by using web application, but it does not work.
So my question would be what is another way to find/get app elements?

**EDITED:**
xpath do not help. Here is my code:

```
public void findButton() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]"));
}
```

Comment: Which technology is your app developed in ?

Answer (score 1):

Web application don't usually have all the elements we expect to use. Instead what you can do, use the class name/index, filter it and use it as your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- Need to move the control from Native app to Web View (where page is rendered using webview)

```
driver.context("web_view");
```

Step 2 - Connect the device to system via USB, and open browser with URL chrome://inspect ....

Step 3 - Identify the particular element

Answer (score 0):

Change the view to
webview.

```
Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {

System.out.println(contextNames);

}
driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.xxx.yyy.zzzz");
```

It will print the context as Native ,`WEBVIEW_com.xxx.yyy.zzzz` , then you
have to change the context to WEBVIEW in order to automate the hybrid app .

```
eg: driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.xxx.yyy.zzzz");
```

driver.context -->it will switch the context